# Selecting top taxa in phyloseq without having multiple unidentified

Tags: r, phyloseq

I need to plot my data's community composition but I'm having a bit of a problem when selecting the 20 most abundant taxa.

I have multiple unidentified taxa at various taxa ranks in my taxonomy table (all under the same "unidentified" label). So when I want to select the top 20 taxa for example, I will have only 15 different taxa in the plot, because 6 of the 20 top taxa are "unidentified" ones.

To select my taxa I ran the following bit of code:

```
ps #phyloseq object
#agglomerate taxa at desired level : Family 
ps_family <-tax_glom(ps, taxrank="Family") 
#then select number of taxa to plot: n=20 
family20 = names(sort(taxa_sums(ps_family), TRUE)[1:20])
#subset phyloseq object to only selected taxa
ps_20 <- prune_taxa(family20, ps) 
#check selected taxa
taxatab <- as.data.frame(tax_table(ps_20))
```

The head of the taxtab dataframe looks something like this :

[taxtab dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZbRb.png)

As you can see there is multiple unidentified taxa but they don't have the same taxonomy, which is why they were not agglomerated together at the Family level.

So when I plot the composition it gives only 15 families:

[community_composition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZX8J.png)

Don't mind the hundreds of samples haha, that's another problem I know how to solve.

My problem stems from the agglomeration step `tax_glom()`, because the unidentified Families may have different Order, Class or Phylum, and won't be agglomerated together at the Family level.
Which means that when I plot my community composition at the Family level, those different unidentified taxa will be grouped under 1 "unidentified" in the legend.

To be clear, I don't want 6 different unidentified in the legend, but I want all the unidentified at the Family rank to be agglomerated so I can have different 20 taxa in my plot.

I would welcome any help you could provide me :)